# Where can I get real-time equity options quotes for a reasonable price (i am not a company) besides screen scrapping Yahoo! Finance?

Tags: options, equities, market-data, electronic-trading, feed

Want to have electronic access to equity options quotes in real-time. Is there anyone offering this service to the individual investor for a reasonable price? Again it must be electronic, in other words, a computer program will analyse the data in real time, not the human eye.

Comment: to me this is not a dup because the other post doesnt necessarily highlight intraday data.

Answer (score 1):

DTN IQFeed, among many others, I'm sure.